# SQL- Find the price of the smallest product in a store

Tags: sql, t-sql, window-functions

I would like to find the price of the smallest product in a store and in addition, in another column, populate this price in all the products of the same store.
Here is my table and the desired result in the "results" column:

[Table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckuCN.png)

Here is my request but it does not populate the price:

`SELECT     local ,product ,price ,IIF(MIN(Product) OVER (PARTITION BY Local)=Product,Price,NULL) as Results FROM Table1`

Thanks

Comment: Do you happen to mean "cheapest" and not "smallest"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want price of the smallest product:

```
  SELECT local, product, price, MAX(CASE WHEN product=MinProd THEN price ELSE 0 
  END) OVER (PARTITION BY Local)Results
    FROM
    (
    SELECT local, product, price, min(product) OVER (PARTITION BY Local) as 
    MinProd FROM Table1
    )
    X
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below -

```
SELECT local, product, price, min(price) OVER (PARTITION BY Local) as result
FROM Table1
```